# Using a file path as an argument to system() to execute C code

Tags: r, directory, executable

I have some C code that transforms some data into a different format. My goal is that the R user inputs the file path, and then runs the executable (which came from the C code). I have been having some issues with this however. It seems to not be reading the file path properly. `Translator` accepts one argument: the file path as the form seen below.

My code: `system("Translator C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\data.csv")`

Running this prints the error in my C code `File not read`. I ran the executable directly and it worked just fine, so it is not a problem with my C code, but how I am calling it in R.

I have tried several different variations of the above code, such as

`system2("Translator", args = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\data.csv")`

`system(paste("Translator C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\data.csv, collapse = " "))`

However, these have not yielded any success. I believe the issue is stemming from the fact that R is not reading the path the way I want it to due to the `\\`. R reads directories as `/` I believe. However, `fopen` in C interprets the directory using `\`. Is there a way use `\` in R, or is this an issue that should be solved in C?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this format a shot: 
Basically `capture.output` should push the `cat` result of the `normalizePath` function in a 'native' WINdows path format to the `system2` command:

```
system2( command = "Translator", args = capture.output( cat(normalizePath(pathToFile)) ) )
```

in this case `pathToFile` can be kept in 'regular' R path format ie: `"C:/Users/user/Documents/data.csv"` should be possible to keep.

Comment: PS: I am not 100% sure if I used to enclose `capture.ouput(…)` in `paste0` on top of it all ie `paste0(capture.output(cat(normaliePath( …))))` - just test what works best for you; usually I would perform all these actions on a string variable containing the parameters to `args =`